# how to resolve django make migrations error

Tags: python, django

I get the following error each time I'm running "python manage.py makemigrations"
This error started when I had issues with git so I had to revert and overwrite some commits.
Someone should help please, because its not allowing me migrate new module, although the server is running currently.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ulaitor/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ulaitor/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ulaitor/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ulaitor/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ulaitor/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ulaitor/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 141, in handle
    loader.project_state(),
  File "/home/ulaitor/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 324, in project_state
    return self.graph.make_state(nodes=nodes, at_end=at_end, real_apps=list(self.unmigrated_apps))
  File "/home/ulaitor/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 315, in make_state
    project_state = self.nodes[node].mutate_state(project_state, preserve=False)
  File "/home/ulaitor/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 87, in mutate_state
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
  File "/home/ulaitor/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 172, in state_forwards
    delay = not old_field.is_relation
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_relation'
```

Comment: My _guess_ is that messing with the history has left you with a migration file that is attempting to modify a field that doesn't exist in the previous version of the model...

Comment: Can you share you Data Table(django model) please?